# How do I convert between time formats?

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I am looking to convert a `MySQL timestamp` to a epoch time in seconds using `PHP`, and vice versa.

What's the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

See [strtotime](http://www.php.net/strtotime) and [date](http://www.php.net/date) functions in PHP manual.

```
$unixTimestamp = strtotime($mysqlDate);
$mysqlDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', $unixTimestamp);
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two functions in MySQL which are useful for converting back and forth from the unix epoch time that PHP likes:

[from_unixtime()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

[unix_timestamp()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

For example, to get it back in PHP unix time, you could do:

```
SELECT unix_timestamp(timestamp_col) FROM tbl WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

From MySQL timestamp to epoch seconds:

```
strtotime($mysql_timestamp);
```

From epoch seconds to MySQL timestamp:

```
$mysql_timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```