# Getting a Date Range in MySQL form a UNIX Timestamp in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, time, timestamp

I have a UNIX timestamp in a table like `1321521158` and want to get the details from a table  for the particular date, like:

```
$mydate="11/11/2011";
SELECT notes FROM table WHERE `addeddate`=$mydate
```

How do I get it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115428/how-do-i-convert-between-time-formats

Answer (score 0):

you can use the mysql date function like:

```
WHERE date(addedate) = date(mydate)
```

or you can calculate the starting and ending timestamp for the given day you want to know and then do

```
WHERE addeddate >= mystarttimestamp AND addeddate <= myendtimestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
  WHERE $mydate = FROM_UNIXTIME('dateColumn')'%Y/%D/%M');
```

[MySQL Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)